# Solidity сomparison of values conditions exception

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How in Solidity comparison without cast value ?

```
 uint balance = 0;
 uint256 Price = 1 ether;
```

and i get **exception** here:

```
console.log(balance - Price >= 0);

0 - 1000000000000000000 >= 0 
-1000000000000000000 >= 0 
false
```

Why is there an error here, and how do I fix it?
As you can see I have no assignment to any type that could cause an error.

Comment: Can you add more details about your issue?

Comment: You can run this example and get unhandled exception on comparison line

Answer (score 1):

`balance - Price` is a calculation of `uint` since the type of each variable is `uint`.
`uint` types can't be a negative value.
The result of `balance - Price` is `-1000000000000000000` but it's not a `uint`.
Therefore, it fails.
If the variable types are `int`, it may works.
Why don't you just write it as below?

```
console.log(balance >= Price);
```

Comment: This is the first time in programming languages encounter such strange RUNTIME behavior. (evm...). This is a comparison, that is, without assigning... I understand if I assign the result to a uint, but here it's just a comparison...

Comment: I think it's same in the programming languages which provide unsigned types